# Why use Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() with try/ catch

Tags: java, multithreading

I have found this structure popular in the multithreading chapter of *Thinking in java*:

```
public void run(){
    try{
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            // do something blocked like wait(), sleep() or I/O
        }
    }catch(InterruptedExeption e){

    }
}
```

However I think now that the while loop will exit if and only if the blocked `wait()`, `sleep()` or `I/O` throws `InterruptedExeption`, why not use `while(true)` instead? Or just because the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is just canonical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself the check for interruption is unnecessary since all the Runnable does is sleep.  But as you can tell from the comment  this is intended as a model for bigger routines. While sleep and wait throw InterruptedException, blocking I/O calls (listed in the comment) won't, and CPU-intensive code that doesn't wait or sleep won't.

What Bruce E is doing here is providing a template for you to follow that handles both the case where an InterruptedException is thrown (where he uses it to exit the loop) and also handles the cases where no sleep or wait is involved and no InterruptedException is thrown. It lets readers know they have an option to check the flag explicitly, and demonstrates the correct way to do so (as opposed to using the interrupted method, which clears the flag).

Comment: Yes **but** this "template" is only really useful for a runnable which repeatedly loops a fairly fast operation. Anything slow you put in the loop body will still take a while to terminate (and in that case, maybe *that* code should be periodically checking the flag, if possible). Anything that doesn't loop can't use this template. As a template, it's actually incredibly niche.

Comment: @michael: it's just a starting point. It's good to let people  know that the isInterrupted method is there.

Comment: Well it's a bad starting point. Just because it's in a book doesn't mean it's any good. There are better, [less confusing ways of introducing `isInterrupted`](https://ideone.com/Su0YsD).

Answer (score 0):

You can also interrupt the Thread with `Thread.interrupt()` from the outside. So to say it's basically an in-build boolean flag.

In this case you are right. You could use `while(true)` since it will break out of the loop when an `InterruptedException` occurs. The author probably wanted to explain it in a cohesive matter. There is probably a chapter on how you would stop a endless Thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is a contrived and rather bad example. You're right that a `while (true)` is a perfectly fine substitute.

`sleep` and `wait` *already* check this same flag. They use this to know whether to throw the exception or not.

Therefore this code:

```
public void run(){
    try{
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }catch(InterruptedExeption e){

    }
}
```

basically represents this kind of logic (pseudo-code):

```
try {
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
    {
        /* Thread.sleep */
        boolean keepSleeping = true;
        while(keepSleeping)
        {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                throw new InterruptedExeption();
            }
            actualSleep(/*a very small amount of time*/);
            if (/* we've slept long enough*/)
            {
                keepSleeping = false;
            }
        }
        /* End Thread.sleep */
    }
}catch(InterruptedExeption e){

}
```

which is clearly kind of convoluted and pointless.

What's more, `Thread.sleep` actually calls `interrupted` rather than `isInterrupted` which is subtly different in that it *actually resets the flag* back so the thread appears uninterrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently according to the [API Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--):

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then **its interrupt status will be *cleared* and it will receive an InterruptedException**.

So the return value of `isInterrupted()` and the `InterruptedException` don't necessarily mean the same thing. See the API doc for some more other conditions.

Comment: So, in fact, if the thread is calling `wait` or `sleep`, those methods will be resetting that flag *anyway*, making checking it from the outside while-loop almost pointless.

Comment: @Michael I agree. Indeed I don't remember ever calling `isInterrupted()` in my code. My answer is just trying to find some rationale for the sample code in the book.

Comment: Here's [a good article](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/10/20/interrupted-exception.html) concerning this if you're interested.